# How to pipe HLS segment to numpy array with FFmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, opencv

I'm trying to extract a clip from an HLS stream and pipe the output to a numpy array. When I set the ffmpeg process to output to an mp4 file, the video looks exactly as I expect it to. However, when I output to a pipe so that I can add the data to a numpy array, the resulting video's display is off.

I'm running this ffmpeg command as a subprocess in python. I retrieve the output and send it to videowriter to create the mp4. I'm only doing the second part at the moment to test that the video data is correct.

```
clip_command = f"ffmpeg -y -live_start_index 0 -i master.m3u8 -ss {start} -t {duration} -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo pipe:1"
generate_clip = Popen(clip_command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=10**8)

nb_img = 300*300*3
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 15, (300, 300))
while True:
    buffer = generate_clip.stdout.read(nb_img)
    if len(buffer) != nb_img:
        # last frame
        break
    img = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype='uint8').reshape(300, 300, 3)
    out.write(img)
out.release()
```

When I view the video that is generated frm cv2.VideoWriter, it looks something like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzBJU.png).
The colors are changed from the source video and the frame repeats near the edges. I've tried setting different values for -pix_fmt but nothing seems to help. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if what I'm trying to do is even feasible with Ffmpeg because I haven't been able to find much information on this particular use case.

Comment: why would you do this? VideoWriter also just uses ffmpeg. why would you take frames from an ffmpeg subprocess, only to give them to VideoWriter, which merely hands them back to another instance (library) of ffmpeg? it's wasteful. just use ffmpeg for the entire thing.

Comment: Yeah I'm just using VideoWriter here to check the frames. What I wanted to do is send the bytes that are output from the ffmpeg subprocess somewhere else and then stitch it back into a video on the other end. So everything after the subprocess would be happening somewhere else.

Comment: Replace `-pix_fmt rgb24` with `-pix_fmt bgr24` (because OpenCV uses BGR ordering). Remove `stderr=STDOUT`. `shell=True` is not recommended. It is recommended to use `Popen(shlex.split(clip_command), ...`. Frame repeats near the edges may still be an issue.